# create Qt project on windows operating system

Tags: windows, qt

i to create a QT project under windows operating system but when i try to run this application i found this error:

```
Starting C:\Source\test1\debug\test.exe...
The process could not be started!
```

can any one help me to know what is the problem

Comment: Duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393512/qt-creator-wont-run-app-after-compiling

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to invoke this from an I.D.E. (like QT Creator) that can't find the executable.
Assuming it has been compiled, the I.D.E. may be trying to call it from the wrong directory.

Look in C:\Source\test1\debug and see if that executable exists.

If it's not there, it probably *should* be looking in C:\Source\test1\release.

Look there for the executable.

For QT Creator: I've found in the past that deleting the *.pro.user file and reopening the project works. The I.D.E. will ask/(force?) you to regenerate this file. Do so. This seems to fix many problems like this.

If you are using an I.D.E. as mentioned, it seems that your project configuration is broken. Save all source files and start a new project with the source files, and let the I.D.E. regenerate its scripts. Check the makefile for errors.